# Gulp install error

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

So I've been trying to install gulp. I've followed the documentation on its official git page and I've gone though different threats here on SO.

So far i've used the commands: npm install --global gulp-cli and npm install --save-dev gulp

[error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzH7W.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your NODE_HOME is proper. On the contrary you can just provide the fully qualified path as the initial gulp command then the task name. Try that too if that works.

Comment: how do i check that??

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

This has always worked for me in the past.

You might also want to check that you have nodejs installed. To check this, use:

```
node -v
```

If you don't, you can download it from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: There is some discussion on SO about whether it is necessary to install gulp both locally and globally.  You installed the cli globally but the gulp package only locally.  As Kylar says try installing gulp globlly and see if you still have errors.